# Facebook Comments Mirroring - How to Reset a Webpage URL

Tags: web-development, facebook, social-media

I created a comments plugin for my website, specified the page URL, inserted my APP ID in a meta tag. My app is public and available to all users. In the Moderation Tool, I enabled comments mirroring and selected my public page as target. I manually shared the URL in a post on my public Facebook page.

Problem: I cannot enable comments mirroring on this URL. The status is "Also post on Facebook" instead of "Your comment may also appear on XYZ's Facebook Page.". I just tried and it works on other URLs. How could I reset the problematic URL?

---

Comment Mirroring allows people to participate in a single
conversation, whether comments come from your webpage or from your
Facebook Page.

- Comments Plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/
- Sharing Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: FB thread on that bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624076297911442/

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: add # at the end of URL and post this new URL

Tip: While creating your FB post, you must paste the whole new URL. Don't paste the old one and append #.